# Is pith a ground tissue with no specialized function?

Tags: botany, homework, terminology, plant-anatomy, tissue

Here is a question from the book *My Max Score SAT Biology E/M Subject Test* (where the SAT is the exam taken by American high school students):

> Ground tissue with no specialized function
>   A. Xylem
>   B. Phloem
>   C. Cambium
>   D. Bark
>   E. Pith

Here, I can eliminate A, B, and D because these are dermal and vascular tissues while a ground tissue is what's between those.

As for the remaining variants, cambium is a tissue that gives rise to other tissues and is responsible for the plant's growth up and to the sides. Pith is a tissue in the very center of the plant stem and is responsible for storage of nutrients. While trying to understand the question, I even found info that it is a type of vascular tissue because it is involved in plant transport (https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-functions-of-piths-in-a-plant) although I'm not sure if it's correct (yeah, I know that Quora is not the website with absolutely credible info).

So, as I can see, both cambium and pith have their function.
Then, I decided to determine whether they are a kind of ground tissue. Pith definitely is a ground tissue, according to its definitions. However, I could not find what kind of tissue cambium was considered to be.
With all that said, I can't be sure to choose either answer. First, both tissues have their functions. Second, pith is a ground tissue, and cambium is undetermined for me.
Here is the answer, however:

> E. Pith is a source of unspecialized ground tissue that adds structure
>   to a stem at the very center.

I can't be sure about this answer because unspecialized means "not designed for a particular purpose." But, as I've pointed out, both pith and cambium have their purposes/functions.
Please explain why pith is written to be unspecialized. Is it because "storage" is not an "active" function like growth or transport; this tissue just exists and is able to store different substances in addition to that?

Also, is cambium a ground tissue or some other type (dermal, vascular)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it's not the greatest question.

Long Answer:

So there are three primary tissues in a plant: ground tissue, dermal tissue, and vascular tissue. See below for how they sort out:

[image]

However, some sources refer to the tissues of plants slightly differently, and indicate that the three basic tissue types are parenchyma, collenchyma, and schlerenchyma.

- Example: "Botany: A Lab Manual" by Pfluger 2014:

  > The three fundemental tissues of plants are parenchyma, collenchyma, and sclerenchyma

Since these are all "ground" tissues, this approach to classifying plant tissues would suggest that *all* plant parts consist of some kind of ground tissue (including all the plant parts you mention in your post). In fact, this is often the case...

- Again, from Pfluger 2014:

  > They [parenchyma] can be found in virtually any part of the plant and are the most common cell type in a plant.

Of the parts you mention, xylem is "specialized" to move water through the plant via tracheids, pits, and vessel elements; phloem moves sugars/sap through sieve tube cells which are supported by companion cells; cambium acts in secondary growth of wood and bark via the vascular and cork cambia; and bark is a water-proof protective layer.

However, "pith" is simply the central parenchyma cells in the stem, and therefore are primarily just used for storage like "all unspecialized" ground tissue.

As for cambium: from [here](https://mmegias.webs.uvigo.es/02-english/1-vegetal/v-imagenes-grandes/cambium_vascular.php):

> Interfascicular cambium differentiates from parenchyma or collenchyma cells located between the vascular bundles (mainly in stem)